# remove dynamic ID at the click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form that generates several input fields, colors for a filter.
With JQuery, I generate a dynamic ID for all the fields and during a "Click" event, I ask it to create a DIV to display my filter if my field is not checked, so far everything works.

Where I can't find the correct code writing is when:
during a "Click" event, if my field is checked I want to dynamically delete the DIV created `$newDivCouleur`

```
var couleurUnique = 1;

$("[id^=branche_search_form_couleurs_").on("click", function() {    
  if (!$(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
    var $newDivCouleur = $('<div class="poPupFiltre"><div class="sousBlockPoPup"><a href="#" class="aPoPup"><img class="img-fluid imgPoPup" src="{{ asset ('../build/images/supprimer.svg') }}" alt=""></a><p class="textPopUp"></p></div></div>');
    $newDivCouleur.attr("id", "PopUpCouleur_" + couleurUnique++);
    $($newDivCouleur).appendTo(".maxWidthPoPup").find(".textPopUp").html($(this).val()); 
  } else {
    console.log("TEST");
    $(this).closest($newDivCouleur).remove(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use dynamically generated `id` attributes. It's an anti-pattern. There are several other better ways to achieve whatever it is you're doing, but we need more details on how and when the elements are created, and how they are interacted with. A full example showing the relevant HTML and JS would be helpful.

Comment: could you possibly use a class instead of an Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var couleurUnique = 1;

$("[id^=branche_search_form_couleurs_]").on("click", function() {    
  if (!$(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
      var $newDivCouleur = $('<div class="poPupFiltre '+$(this).attr('id')+'"><div class="sousBlockPoPup"><a href="#" class="aPoPup"><img class="img-fluid imgPoPup" src="#" alt=""></a><p class="textPopUp"></p></div></div>');
      $newDivCouleur.attr("id", "PopUpCouleur_" + couleurUnique++);
    
   $($newDivCouleur).appendTo(".maxWidthPoPup").find(".textPopUp").html($(this).val()); 
  } else {
      console.log("TEST");
      $(document).find(".poPupFiltre."+$(this).attr('id')).remove(); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="branche_search_form_couleurs_1" />

<input type="checkbox" id="branche_search_form_couleurs_2" />

<div class="maxWidthPoPup">
    <div class="textPopUp"></div>
</div>
```

I think you need something like this,

What I have done is just add a class with the reference id of checkbox when it's unchecked the class matches with the selected checkbox id will be removed.